# Add column to pandas dataframe for multi index

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I'm reading in several large (~700mb) CSV files to convert to a dataframe, which will all be combined into a single CSV. Right now each CSV is index by the `date` column in each CSV. All of the CSV's have overlapping dates, but have unique testing locations. Each CSV is named by its testing location (e.g ber.csv and alt.csv for BER and ALT testing sites). How can I multi index like this? Right now I have:

```
def openFile(filesToProcess):
    df1 = pd.DataFrame()
    counter = 0
    for input in filesToProcess:
        base = os.path.splitext(basename(input))[0]
        print "Working on %s" % base
        with open(input, 'r') as input_file:
            #row_count = sum(1 for row in input_file)
            if counter == 0:
                df1 = createDataFrame(input_file)
            else:
                df2 = createDataFrame(input_file)
                df1 = pd.concat([df1,df2])
        counter += 1
        input_file.close()
    df1.to_csv('large.csv')

def createDataFrame(input_file):
    checkTime = time.clock()
    #print "Start DataFrame -- #%d" % counter
    df1 = pd.read_csv(input_file,
            sep = ",",
            nrows = 500,
            index_col = ['Date'])
    #print "End DataFrame -- #%d" % counter
    #print "Ran for " + str(time.clock() - checkTime) + " Seconds"
    return df1
```

So for instance I'd like

```
date, testsite, data1, data2
1/1/1992  9:15:00, ber, 89, 200
1/1/1992  9:17:00, ber, 54, 103.3
1/1/1992  9:15:00, alt, 90, 109.23
1/1/1992  9:17:00, alt, 12, 110.1
```

where `date` and `testsite` are the multi index

Answer (score 0):

***setup***

```
ber_df = pd.DataFrame([[89, 200], [54, 103.3]],
                      pd.DatetimeIndex(['1/1/1992  9:15:00', '1/1/1992  9:17:00'],
                                       name='date'),
                      ['data1', 'data2'])


alt_df = pd.DataFrame([[90, 109.23], [12, 110.1]],
                      pd.DatetimeIndex(['1/1/1992  9:15:00', '1/1/1992  9:17:00'],
                                       name='date'),
                      ['data1', 'data2'])


ber_df.to_csv('ber.csv')

alt_df.to_csv('alt.csv')
```

***solution***

```
filesToProcess = ['ber.csv', 'alt.csv']

def parse_file(fn):
    return pd.read_csv(fn, index_col=0, parse_dates=[0])

pd.concat({fn.replace('.csv', ''): parse_file(fn) for fn in filesToProcess}) \
    .rename_axis(['testsite', 'date'], axis=0).swaplevel(0, 1).reset_index()
```

[image]